# Find if decimal lat and long falls with a particular range in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have 2 tables, one with columns `id`, date/time, latitude and longitude. The other table has columns company id, latitude and longitude. The lat and longs are in decimals in both tables.

How would I take the lat and longs in table 1 and see if they are within .0005 of a company in table 2 and then return the company name? The query I am using is a sub query that can be found below.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: .0005 what? Miles? degrees? And it looks like you forgot to add the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like:

```
Select 
    Table1.*
From
    Table1,
    Table2
Where
    Abs(Table1.Latitude - Table2.Latitude) < 0.0005
    And
    Abs(Table1.Longitude - Table2.Longitude) < 0.0005
```

Expand the *Where* clause to filter on *one company* only, if that is your task.
Then either this company (success) or an empty recordset (failure) would be returned.